# Basic f# error - pattern matching is implying the wrong type

Tags: f#

The following code takes 2 parameters. the first is a list of triples: The triple (d,m,y) is meant to represent a date.

the second is an integer which is a month

The code is meant to count the number of occurrences of dates with that month in the list

p.s. I guess this probably looks like a homework question - it's not. It's from a course I did earlier in the year in ML and I'm trying to redo all the exercises in f#. So it's only for my benefit

```
let rec number_in_month (dates : (int * int * int) list, month) =  
    match dates with
    | [] -> 0
    | (_,y,_) when month = y -> 1 + number_in_month(dates.Tail, month)
    | _ -> number_in_month(dates.Tail, month)
```

but it gives the error :

> This expression was expected to have type
>       (int * int * int) list     but here has type
>       'a * 'b * 'c

any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Actually, there is no value in typing your list int*int*int, is there ? Can't you just make it `(dates : ('a* 'b* 'c) list` ?

Comment: I get a similar error if I do that : This expression was expected to have type
    ('a * 'b * 'c) list    
but here has type
    'd * 'e * 'f

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your second pattern match is trying to match a single date `(_,y,_)` but it is being matched against your list of dates.  Try matching using `(_,y,_)::_` instead.

More idiomatic would be to match using `(_,y,_)::tail` and to use `tail` instead of `dates.Tail` later in the expression.

Comment: ah - of course - that makes perfect sense now you point it out - thanks. Also - I suspect I'm defining  the parameters incorrectly? As they are a tuple if I'm putting them in bracket, right? What would be the correct to do this as a regular curried function?

Comment: Just spaces instead of brackets\commas.

Answer (score 1):

The code can also be tightened up  (including the fix MarkP suggested). Note the use of type inference so that the type of `dates` does not need to be passed

```
let rec number_in_month dates month = 
    match dates with
        | [] -> 0
        | (_,y,_)::tail ->       
           ( number_in_month tail month) + (if y = month then 1 else 0)


let data = [(1,2,3);(1,2,3);(1,5,7);(1,9,2);(1,9,2);(1,9,2)]

number_in_month data 5
number_in_month data 2
```

http://www.tryfsharp.org/create/bradgonesurfing/datefinder.fsx